# Алгоритм шифрования

Tags: криптография, шифрование

Планирую написать веб приложение на сервер для хранения паролей (есть существующие системы, знаю, но задача поставлена с целью приобретения опыта) вопрос подошел к выбору криптоалгоритма, признаюсь, честно, я в них плохо разбираюсь, а все досконально изучать нет ни времени ни энтузиазма, нужен алгоритм, который бы шифровал данные в удобный для хранения в `MySQL` вид, но из задачи следует что обратный результат тоже необходимо получить. Ну я думаю, вы меня понимаете, помогите с выбором с точки зрения криптостойкости, желательно с аргументами.

Comment: "Обратный результат" - это изначальный пароль? Если да, то возникает вопрос: зачем?

Comment: Ну смотря что иметь ввиду под обратным результатом. Если предусматривается возможность иметь дешифрацию по определению, то тогда и шифровать особо круто и не требуется (смысл-то какой от "крутости" уровня шифрования?). С таким успехом можете применить `base64_encode` / `base64_decode`, только с результатом, "помноженным" на пару *солей*, известным уж тогда только тем людям, которым надлежит по праву иметь возможность знать обратную процедуру. Метод вполне серьезно используется на коммерческих платформах.

P.S. *..или уточните задачу*

Comment: Не знаю, что имел в виду автор, а я бы представил это как задачу хранения коротких независимых друг от друга слов в зашифрованном виде.

Т.е. представим, что это пароли вовсе не от того сервера, на котором они хранятся. И на нем они никогда не проверяются. Просто отсылаются на сервер, хранятся зашифрованными и могут быть запрошены автором (владельцем) в расшифрованном виде.

Соответственно, нужна какая-то надежная схема (включающая управление ключами шифрования) их шифрации-передачи-хранения-дешифрации владельцем. 

--

Естественно, эти соображения  просто сеанс телепатии :)

Comment: из разряда lastpass ? шифруйте пароль открытым ключём, есть RSA библиотеки для js. закрытый ключ можно так-же хранить на сервере, запароленым.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо смотреть в сторону блочных симметричных шифров (долго объяснять почему). А таковых не так уж и много. DES (легко расшифровываемый), AES (говорят есть бэкдор, правда я не верю), BlowFish - ну вроде как слабоват, Anubis, IDEA - то что надо. Все остальные в той или иной мере вариации этих алгоритмов (есть конечно и экзотика, но еще надо поискать их реализации).

Я бы лично, не стал особо заморачиваться и взял AES (реализован везде), только обратил особое внимание на режим сцепления блоков - это слабое место любого блочного алгоритма. Блочные алгоритмы кодируют блоки информации по 64/128 и т.д. бит, чтобы избежать атаки по маске эти блоки необходимо перемешивать с чем-то и сцеплять - это и называется [режимом/модой сцепления](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) - рекомендую режим CBC - прост как автомат Калашникова, а убойная сила достаточная.

Comment: Я бы лично, не стал особо заморачиваться и взял AES (реализован везде)

Сравнил результаты гугла на предмет AES и Anubis - первый гораздо больше выдает о попытках взломов. Думаю, можно это считать фактором... Система такова, что в mysql хранятся только шифрованные данные. Гипотетически если взломщик получит БД, то пользы он мало получит без ключа. Anubis как-то больше симпатизирует, менее известный, но в этом его преимущество. Если взломщик попытается взломать, в его вооружении будет меньше информации, так я думаю... Спасибо большое, вы мне помогли.

Comment: Я тоже симпатизирую Анубису, даже знаком с разработчиками... Не знаю в какой среде вы будете реализовывать шифровку, но с Анубисом придется повозиться. В стандартных либах он отсутствует.

Comment: PHP, нашел на гитхабе класс для работы с Анубисом. https://github.com/kolonist/php-anubis

Comment: @Андрей Таланин прежде чем применять проверь на тестовые вектора Анубиса - [они лежат здесь](http://www.larc.usp.br/~pbarreto/AnubisPage.html)